# Как сделать нумерацию строк в QTextEdit?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qtextedit

Как это делать? Помогите реализовать нумерацию строк.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QMenu, QAction, QFileDialog
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
    
        self.setWindowTitle('Редактор кода')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 900, 500)
        self.create_editor()

    def create_editor(self):
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.editor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class LineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class PlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)
        
        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)
        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)
        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1
        
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = PlainTextEdit()
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @HdndJdndnd что не так?