Как сделать нумерацию строк PyQt5
Всем здравствуйте. Хотел бы у вас спросить: Как сделать нумерация строк в QTextEdit, по типу такого:

hello
lol
kek


отвечает ли  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1571133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-qtextedit/1571140#1571140 на ваш вопрос?
